# SemEval-2016 Task 5 Subtask 2 Evaluation

Tags: nlp, model-evaluations, sentiment-analysis, metric

**Hi, I read SEMEVAL task 5 from this website (https://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task5/) but the evaluation method for subtask 2 is not clear. I really appreciate it if you tell me the method. This is the relevant part of the website:**

Subtask 2: Text-level ABSA. Given a set of customer reviews about a target entity (e.g. a laptop or a restaurant), the goal is to identify a set of {aspect, polarity} tuples that summarize the opinions expressed in each review. For example, for the review text LPT1:

Review id: LPT1 (Laptop)

"The So called laptop Runs to Slow and I hate it! Do not buy it! It is the worst laptop ever."

a system should return the following opinion tuples:

{LAPTOP#OPERATION_PERFORMANCE, negative}
{LAPTOP#GENERAL, negative}

However, this is not a simple summation task given that each aspect may be discussed with different sentiment in several parts of the review. In such cases the dominant sentiment has to be identified. For example, for the restaurant review text RST1:

Review id:RST1 (Restaurant)

"I was very disappointed with this restaurant. I’ve asked a cart attendant for a lotus leaf wrapped rice and she replied back rice and just walked away. I had to ask her three times before she finally came back with the dish I’ve requested. Food was okay, nothing great. Chow fun was dry; pork shu mai was more than usually greasy and had to share a table with loud and rude family. I/we will never go back to this place again."

a system should return the following opinion tuples, since the dominant sentiment about the quality of the food is “negative” and not “neutral”:

{RESTAURANT#GENERAL, negative}
{SERVICE#GENERAL, negative}
{FOOD#QUALITY, negative}
{AMBIENCE#GENERAL, negative}

In the case of conflicting opinions where the dominant sentiment is not clear, the “conflict” label should be assigned. For example, in the following review (RST2) the reviewer expresses a positive opinion about one dish (pad seew chicken) and a negative opinion about another one (pad thai) without providing any further information:

Review id: RST2 (Restaurant)

“This little place has a cute interior decor and affordable city prices. The pad seew chicken was delicious, however the pad thai was far too oily. I would just ask for no oil next time.”

{AMBIENCE#GENERAL, positive}
{RESTAURANT#PRICES, positive}
{FOOD#QUALITY, conflict}
{RESTAURANT#GENERAL, positive}

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Can you please clarify the issue? Btw you didn't copy the part of the document related to evaluation, maybe that's what you're missing?